# How to add option in <redoc>?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, swagger, documentation

I want to add some additional option to my ReDoc. For current implementation I am using json file that is generated from Swagger, and this is added in html page. Example how this is done:

```
  <body>
    <redoc spec-url='http://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json'></redoc>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/redoc@next/bundles/redoc.standalone.js"> </script>
  </body>
```

I use this as referent documentation: https://github.com/Rebilly/ReDoc

How can I add option object in  tag and not use ReDoc object? And how can I use vendor extension e.g. x-logo?
In documentation this is set via json file, but my json file is auto generate from Swagger.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You just place the options after the `spec-url` in the `redoc` tag like this:

```
<body>
    <redoc spec-url='http://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json' YOUR_OPTIONS_HERE></redoc>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/redoc@next/bundles/redoc.standalone.js"> </script>
</body>
```

in this example on ReDoc repository you can verify it (line 22 at this moment):

https://github.com/Rebilly/ReDoc/blob/master/config/docker/index.tpl.html#L22

#### Important:

Remember to *"kebab-casing the ReDoc options"*, as an example if your options are:

`hideDownloadButton noAutoAuth disableSearch`

***YOUR_OPTIONS_HERE***

should be (after kebab-casing them):

`hide-download-button no-auto-auth disable-search`

Your body with those options becomes like this:

```
<body>
    <redoc spec-url='http://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json' hide-download-button no-auto-auth disable-search></redoc>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/redoc@next/bundles/redoc.standalone.js"> </script>
</body>
```

Hope it will be usefull to you.

Answer (score 1):

`ReDoc` has advanced initialization via [`Redoc.init`](https://github.com/Rebilly/ReDoc#advanced-usage-of-standalone-version) so you can download the spec manually and add some postprocessing (e.g. add an `x-logo`).

You can pass ReDoc options as the second argument to `Redoc.init`:

```
<body>
  <div id="redoc"></div>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/redoc@next/bundles/redoc.standalone.js"> </script>
  <script>
    fetch('http://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(spec => {
        spec.info['x-logo'] = { url: "link/to/image.png" };
        Redoc.init(spec, {
        // options go here (e.g. pathInMiddlePanel)
        }, document.getElementById('redoc'));
      });
</body>
```

**NOTE:** This requires [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) to be available in browsers so it won't work in IE11.

Comment: I need to setup Redoc.init in angular 6 app. But not sure how to do it. right now I'm doing the redoc spec-url

Answer (score 1):

You can place your options next to `spec-url`.
Be sure that the version of Redoc you are using, have options you want to use, you can check it by going to the specific version. `github.com/Redocly/redoc/tree/vx.x.x`.
As a side note features lazy-rendering in available till `v1.22.3`.

`https://github.com/Redocly/redoc#redoc-options-object`

`You can use all of the following options with standalone version on tag by kebab-casing them, e.g. scrollYOffset becomes scroll-y-offset and expandResponses becomes expand-responses.`

Comment: Updated [link](https://github.com/Redocly/redoc/blob/main/docs/config.md)